# Access Jumpcut archives?

Tags: macos, mac, copy-paste

I have jumpcut on mac and it is set up to "remember" 40 items, but only 15 items actually show in menu. How can I access the other 25 items?

Answer (score 1):

You can access them from the bezel window (shown by control-option-V by default) by holding the right arrow key.